# What does 'product' => TRUE in hook_commerce_line_item_type_info() do?

Tags: drupal-7, commerce

In hook_commerce_line_item_type_info() there is an option 'product' => TRUE that is used by different implementations.

What does it mean / do?

Answer (score 0):

Boolean indicating whether or not this line item type functions as a product in various systems, such as the Add to Cart form. If set to TRUE, the line item type must also contain the fields added to the base product line item type, commerce_product and commerce_display_path. To achieve this the line item type can reuse the configuration callback of the [Product line item type](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!product_reference!commerce_product_reference.module/function/commerce_product_line_item_configuration/DC).

Comment: Hi, this explanation comes from the example module if I'm right. 'Add to Cart form' uses it. Can you give me more examples.

Comment: Passing very busy time, but I will get back to you with details example